# Advanced custom fields doesn't show after custom post type, how can I make this work?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I have multiple fields from Advanced Custom Fields (wordpress plugin) that work fine on the website. I have 1 custom post type that is displayed also perfectly fine. The problem is that after the custom post type, my Advanced Custom Fields field doesn't appear anymore. The plugin seems to collide with the custom post type. If I post the field to be displayed before the custom post type it works again, but that's not an option.

```
    <div class="container-white-bg">
  <div class="columns">
 <?php 
        $query = array (
            'post_type' => 'dates',
            'order' => 'ID',
            'posts_per_page' => 8
        );

        $queryObject = new WP_Query($query);
        if ( $queryObject->have_posts() ): while ( $queryObject->have_posts() ): $queryObject->the_post(); ?>

<a href="" class="price-block w-inline-block">
          <div class="pb-1"></div>
          <div class="datum">
        <?php $begindatum = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'begindatum', true ); $begindatum = str_replace('（', '<br><span>（', $begindatum); echo str_replace('）', '）</span>', $begindatum); ?>
        <br> - <br>
        <?php $einddatum = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'einddatum', true ); $einddatum = str_replace('（', '<br><span>（', $einddatum); echo str_replace('）', '）</span>', $einddatum); ?>
        </div>
          <div class="prijs"><?php $price = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price', true ); $price = str_replace('（', '<br><span>（', $price); echo str_replace('）', '）</span>', $price); ?></div>
          <div class="periode"><?php $period = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'period', true ); $period = str_replace('（', '<br><span>（', $period); echo str_replace('）', '）</span>', $period); ?></div>
</a><?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="heading">Foto&#x27;s</h2>
        <?php the_field('galerij-homepage'); ?>
  </div>
```

This is the code. the `$query` is where my custom post type starts. The Advanced Custom Field that is not working is `<?php the_field('galerij-homepage'); ?>` I'm literally tied and I can't seem to fix this problem. is it just not possible or am I missing something?

Comment: Reset the query before ACF fields.

Comment: Great! So easy yet so effective. Thanks alot, you saved me a lot of trouble! :)

Answer (score 0):

The guy that posted under my comment solved it. I had to reset the query before the ACF field.

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

That was all.